# сбор определенных данных из файла excel содержащего Nan

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

Нужно собрать из файлов excel, например таких:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

определенные строки

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 text = 'коробк'
 fn = r'c:\Users\ALEX\Downloads\Книга1.xlsx'
 df = pd.read_excel(fn)
 # df.loc[df.isnull()] = 1
 df[df.ix[:,2].str.lower().str.contains(text.lower())]
```

> DeprecationWarning: 
>   .ix is deprecated. Please use
>   .loc for label based indexing or
>   .iloc for positional indexing

с использованием .iloc

```
  df.iloc[df.ix[:,2].str.lower().str.contains(text.lower())]
```

следующая ошибка

> ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values

Comment: В warning вроде всё понятно описано и указано что делать... В чем у вас затруднения?

Answer (score 2):

Метод [.str.contains(pattern)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) ожидает регулярное выражение в качестве первого параметра.

`*` имеет особый смысл в регулярных выражениях - `0 или более повторений предыдущего символа`.

В строке `'*коробк*'` - на первом месте звездочка и перед ней ничего нет, отсюда и ошибка:

> error: nothing to repeat at position 0

Можно просто убрать звездочки:

```
text = 'коробк'
```